# Close iFrame from iFrame content on parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with id as frame like this:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="page.php">
```

From my page.php page i would like to be able to close the iframe on the parent window.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call a javascript function from the child page

`parent.parentFunctionName` should work.

there you can do whatever you want